# Manipulating text in iMessage using iMessage App

Tags: swift, imessage

When building an iMessage app in Swift... is it possible to access text already in the message being formed? Like if I type in: "text that i want to manipulate" and then open the iMessage App I just built in the bottom menu, can I access that string and use it in my app?

Comment: Check out https://developer.apple.com/reference/messages/msconversation. It says you can access information about currently selected message i.e. MSMessage Object and MSMessage object has a property summaryText which gives you concise text not the whole text https://developer.apple.com/reference/messages/msmessage/2132092-summarytext. Apple doesn't allow to access the text of the message as its against the user privacy.